# Turn off continuous scrolling in Azure DevOps

Tags: azure-devops, scroll, backlog

Is there any way to turn off continuous scrolling in Azure DevOps?
Scenario
We have a relatively large Product Backlog (>500) items in Azure DevOps. We currently are unable to search (using CTRL F) due to intelligent pagination. Azure DevOps seems to only create HTML elements for the items on the page.
We have some workarounds for this problem, but ideally, we would like to see what happens when Continuous scrolling is turned off.

I'm unable to find a way to do this, any ideas?

Thanks,

John

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid there is no way to turn off Continuous scrolling.

You can try to use the filter function instead of using Ctrl+F. For more info please refer this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/backlogs/filter-backlogs-boards-plans?view=azure-devops).

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this was one of the workarounds I mentioned. Hopefully, this question will save some other people's time.